# CodeBlocks не ставит автоматические табы

Tags: c++, linux, ide, codeblocks

CodeBlocks на Ubuntu 18.04 не форматирует фигурные скобки как в Windows версии. Подскажите плагин, пожалуйста, которым можно это исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне просто интересно: а чем же эти два варианта отличаются, кроме как комментарием?

Comment: В первом варианте между скобками автоматически  ставиться таб (также они разделяются строкой) , и в месте комментария уже стоит курсор, когда во втором варианте ничего не происходит.

Comment: во втором варианте у вас разделяющего комментария нету, соответственно что вы там хотите увидеть?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы когда я ставил { и нажимал "Enter" закрывающая скобка переносилась на 2 строки вниз, а между ними автоматически ставилась табуляция. Если не ошибаюсь это называют: "Умный отступ".

Comment: нет, ошибаетесь, умный отступ, это когда после нажатия enter курсор просто перемещается на строку ниже с сохранением отступа + дополнительный отступ в определенных случаях. Про дополнительную скобку - это уже отдельно.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но вопрос еще актуален.

Comment: По поводу конкретно расставлены скобок во время печати я, к сожалению, ничего не подскажу (так как в принципе не поддерживаю такую концепцию), но могу посоветовать утилиту для форматирования кода после его написания (всмысле она работает лишь во время непосредственного вызова, а не во время печати) - clang-format

Answer (score 1):

```
settings
|_ editor
   |_ source formatter
      |_ style
```

Выбирайте, либо Google, либо Java.